# How do I make an API call and authenticate it with a given API key using Python?

Tags: python, api, parameters, data-science, http-authentication

This is my code to extract player data from an endpoint containing basketball data for a Data Science project.**NOTE:** I changed the name of the actual API key I was given since it's subscription. And I change the username/password because for privacy purposes. Using the correct credentials, I wouldn't receive a syntax error but the status code always returns 401. Since it wasn't accepting the API key, I added my account username, password, and the HTTP authentication header as well, but the status code still returns 401.

**In case this is relevant, this is the website's recommendation in the developer portal:** **The API key can be passed either as a query parameter or using the following HTTP request header.

Please let me know what changes I can make to my code. Any help is appreciated.

Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: {key}**

**PS: My code got fragmented while posting this, but it is all in one function.**

def getData():

```
user_name = "name@gmail.com"
```

api_endpoint = "https://api.sportsdata.io/v3/nba/stats/json/PlayerGameStatsByDate/2020-FEB7"
api_key = "a45;lkf"

```
password = "ksaljd"

header = "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key"
PARAMS = {'user': user_name, 'pass': password, 'header': header, 'key': api_key} 
response = requests.get(url = api_endpoint, data = PARAMS)
print(response.status_code)
file = open("Data.csv", "w")
file.write(response.text)
file.close()
```

Comment: Try to change `'key'` to `'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key'`! If that does not work try `headers={'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '**key**'}` as an additional parameter.

Answer (score 1):

```
def _get_auth_headers() -> dict:
    return {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': "`Insert key here`"
    }
api_endpoint = "https://api.sportsdata.io/v3/nba/stats/json/PlayerGameStatsByDate/2020-FEB7"
PARAMS = {
    # Your params here
}
response = requests.get(
    api_endpoint,
    headers=_get_auth_headers(),
    params=PARAMS
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just a string, you need to pass `dict` in the `headers` parameter and `auth` param exist so you can use it as follow:

```py
def getData():
    [...]

    header = {
        "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": api_key
    }
    
    [...]
    response = requests.get(url = api_endpoint, data = PARAMS, headers=header, auth = (user_name, password))
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [API documentation](https://sportsdata.io/developers/api-documentation/nba) you don't need to provide email and password. You're only need to add your `API Key` to header:

```
import requests

r = requests.get(url='https://api.sportsdata.io/v3/nba/stats/json/PlayerGameStatsByDate/2020-FEB7', headers={'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'API_KEY'})
print(r.json())
```

Output:

```
[{
        'StatID': 768904,
        'TeamID': 25,
        'PlayerID': 20000788,
        'SeasonType': 1,
        'Season': 2020,
        'Name': 'Tim Hardaway Jr.',
        'Team': 'DAL',
        'Position': 'SF',
        'Started': 1,
        'FanDuelSalary': 7183,
        'DraftKingsSalary': 7623,
        'FantasyDataSalary': 7623,
...
```